# puts matches from to files

Tags: ruby

I have mac addresses in mac1.txt and mac2.txt and I wanted to do something like this:

```
v = File.open("/RubyDev/sort/mac1.txt",'r').each_line do |a|
      w = File.open("/RubyDev/sort/mac2.txt",'r').each_line do |b|
            if w in v
                puts w
            end
      end
end
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** That first version below is actually pretty terrible. Here's a better version:

```
lines = []

File.open("mac1.txt",'r').each_line do |a|
  lines.push(a.rstrip!)
end

File.open("mac2.txt",'r').each_line do |b|
  if lines.include?(b.rstrip!)
    puts b
  end
end
```

---

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
File.open("mac1.txt",'r').each_line do |a|
  File.open("mac2.txt",'r').each_line do |b|
    if a == b
      puts b
    end
  end
end
```

Is that correct? If not, could you give more background about the issue and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Array#include isn't very efficient. The hash-based solutions are superior. Also, you don't need the bang-method in the first file.

Comment: Both fair points. I actually hadn't even considered the hash-based comparison idea until after I saw it. I'm pretty green when it comes to Ruby myself, so I didn't know that `include?` was inefficient. Thanks!

Comment: it's not that `include?` is inefficient in itself, but  scanning an array for a matching element is O(n) whereas hash lookup is O(1).

Answer (score 1):

I am still trying to learn Ruby, so this is unlikely a good solution, but it is a possibility.  It reads the contents of the first file into a hash and then checks the contents of the second against it.  I think it would be reasonably efficient (well ... unless the first file is too big to fit nicely in memory).

```
lines = Hash.new

File.open( "mac1.txt", 'r' ).each_line do |l|
    lines[l] = true
end

File.open( "mac2.txt", 'r' ).each_line do |l|
    if ( lines[l] == true )
        puts l
    end
end
```

**Edit** For completeness, here is the very succinct version as suggested in the comments by Mark Thomas with the white space removal suggested by Gavin Anderegg.  Ruby is a sweet language.

```
lines = Hash.new
File.open( "mac1.txt", 'r' ).each_line {|l| lines[l.strip!] = true}
File.open( "mac2.txt", 'r' ).each_line {|l| puts l if lines[l.strip!]}
```

Comment: Not bad. Readmode is default, so you can replace the first section with `File.open("mac1.txt").each_line {|l| lines[l] = true}`. The second can be `File.open("mac2.txt").each_line {|l| puts l if lines[l]}`

Comment: Huh! That's really neat! It still suffers from the "\n" v. "EOF" issue, though. Maybe something like this?

1: `lines = Hash.new` 2: 
`File.open("mac1.txt").each_line {|l| lines[l.rstrip!] = true}` 3: 
`File.open("mac2.txt").each_line {|l| puts l if lines[l.rstrip!]}`

Comment: @Gavin, I'd use `lines[l.chomp]` but that's just personal preference.

Comment: @Mark, @Gavin:  Thanks for the input.  That's good information.  I figured there was a cleaner looking solution.  I really like Ruby because the solutions generally "feel" right and are still very readable.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the common lines between two files, you can use `File#readlines` to access all the lines in the file as an array. Keep in mind that they will still have newlines ("\n") appended, so you'll need to remove them with `String#chomp`. The easiest way to do this is to `map` the array that `readlines` gives you, like this:

```
common_macs = File.open("mac1.txt").readlines.map(&:chomp) & 
  File.open("mac2.txt").readlines.map(&:chomp)
```

Comment: Good explanation, but I don't see how it computes the common macs.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = {}
File.open("mac1.txt").each_line {|l| lines[l.chomp] = true}
File.open("mac2.txt").each_line {|l| puts l if lines[l.chomp]}
```